# Unable to add options on dashboard widget ?

Tags: widgets, admin, dashboard

Source code here : https://pastebin.com/G6VVjEeh

Trying to add option in dashboard widget . On Line 194 add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', function () . . . not triggering . Working Perfect in User's side (display). What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please, add all the needed information to question itself. If the third party site goes down, the question and its answers will lose their meaning making it not useful for users anymore.

Comment: I did posted in the code in the the designated section at first . Somehow the code were getting out of <code></code> section where there is a php comment .

Comment: You must use markdown markup, not HTML. You can use the buttons on the editor while writting your questions, or wrtie markdown directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help If you don't mind, [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/279995/edit) to add all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

`$args['before_widget']` and `$args['afters_widget']` (or `after_widget`) are things you'd add to a front-end sidebar widget. They have no relevance to dashboard widgets. The call to `$args['before_widget']` is likely throwing an error because it's not set.

Also, your `wp_dashboard_setup` hook callback is an anonymous function. This won't work on PHP < 5.3. So double check your PHP version.

Comment: Currenly using PHP 5.6+  so callback should work . (In fact working in my other plug in).

Will remove $args['before_widget'] and $args['afters_widget'] , (Thanks for noticing) . Those were there due to copy paste .